# Connection must be open VB

Tags: vb.net

It says connection must be valid or open? I tried replacing reader with scalar but still the same?

```
account = CType(Session("uname"), String)

    cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE username = @p1")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", account)
    con.Open()
    dat = cmd.ExecuteReader
    dat.Read()
    dat.GetString("acc_pass")
```

Comment: An extra tip:  You should place this code into a a try/catch statement, with a finaly, where you close the connetion again - con.Close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to tell your command your connection...

See below for answer...

```
 cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE username = @p1", con)
```

Also I strongly recommend wrapping this in a using statement, that way objects and such get disposed.